# NameError: name 'api' is not defined for Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn the Django Rest Framework.

I create a project called `djangorest`.
Then I created an app called `api`

In **djangorest/urls.py** I have:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/', include(api.urls)),

]
```

In **djangorest/settings.py** I included the new app `api`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',  
    'api.apps.ApiConfig',
]
```

However, when I run the server I get the error:

> > NameError: name 'api' is not defined

Comment: You forgot to import the `api`. Add `import api.urls` in the `djangorest/urls.py`.

Comment: With `include(api.urls)` you are instructing Django to include the url patterns from another object, where those patterns are taken from the `url` attribute of an object named `api`. If `api` is supposed to be a Python package (all Django apps are) then you forgot to import that package.

Comment: Thanks, api is the name of my app, not a python package. If I add import api.urls, I get "No module named api"

Comment: As @MartijnPieters said, all django apps **are python modules**. Is there an **`__init__.py`** file in your api app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use strings when including URLs.

```
path('api/', include('api.urls')),
```